# detecting ordered words in game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am sorry if this question has been asked already, but I have been stumped on this question for a week now. I have 3 image views, containing three labels. What I need to do, is allow the user to move these image views into alphabetical order. I already have the pan gesture set upon the image views, and the labels are already set for everything. I just need help on figuring out how to get the labels to be detected as they are moved around. I have the label(s) text set into a mutable array, and as I do the checking it seems to run only off the array, instead of the actual labels. This is really the first time I have every done anything this complex. I hope this makes sense. Here is the code that I have, any help is appreciated.

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
if ([pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:[[pan view] superview]];

    [[pan view] setCenter:CGPointMake([[pan view] center].x + translation.x, [[pan view] center].y + translation.y)];
    [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[[pan view] superview]];
}
@try {
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        for (int i = 0; i < self.alphabeticalWords.count; i++) {
            NSString *labelTextBefore = [self.labels[i] text];
            NSString *labelTextAfter = [self.labels[i+1] text];

            if ([labelTextBefore compare:labelTextAfter] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"Alphabetical");
                [self completedLevel];
                self.alphabeticalWords = nil;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"First two are not alphabetical!");
                labelTextAfter = labelTextBefore;
                labelTextBefore = labelTextAfter;
            }
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Method: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
@finally {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use try/catch in normal operation. In Objective C/Cocoa you should avoid exceptions, not code to trap them.

As for your problem, you need a way to convert from position on the screen to order.

Is the user supposed to drag the words into the yellow boxes in the correct order? Don't you want some way to let the user drag into the boxes so the boxes highlight, and when the user releases the object, it snaps to the middle of the box? That would make for a better user experience. You could use the CGRectContainsPoint() function to tell if the center of the car object is inside the rectangle. When the car's center enters a box you could fill the center or draw the box in a different color to show that box is the target. Then when the user releases you could snap the car into that box.

Then, since your code now knows which box the car is in, you could assign it a value 1/2/3 based on the box that received the car.

Comment: I understand your concept, but could you provide me with something in code/psuedocode to kind of get it all figured out?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array called `alphabeticalWords`, which is sorted in alphabetical order, and another array called `labels`, which the user is realigning, can't you just check that the text in each label matches the text in each string in `alphabeticalWords`? E.g.

```
BOOL ordered = YES;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [alphabeticalWords count]; ++i)
{
    if ([[(UILabel *)labels[i] text] isEqualToString:alphabeticalWords[i]] == NO)
    {
        ordered = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```